# How can I vertically center a Multiline Textfield (dynamic, text-centered) to another MovieClip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

Normally, to center an instance on the stage to another vertically horizontally, you can use simple logic and by referencing width, height, x and y co-ordinates of the symbols involved.

This seems impossible in-situ, because Textfield.height and Textfield.textHeight report incorrect values. They bring back the same values, which don't reflect the actual height of the instance on the stage.

[image]

<del>I have crafted this simple example to illustrate the problem: http://omnom.replete.nu/fails.fla</del>

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the TextField does not relate to the Height of the text itself.
Text height can change for a number of reasons.
A good example would be the font family and font sizes.
You need to use text metrics to get that info.
[ALL THE INFO HERE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html)

[EDIT]
per your comments the last line of your scaleTextToFitInTextField function should do this.
you need to find the center of both objects and subtract them then add the offset

```
txt.x = cont.width/2 - txt.width/2 + cont.x
txt.y = cont.height/2 - txt.height/2 + cont.y
```

[EDIT EDIT]
Also remove these 2 lines as they are now redundant

```
red.tf.x = red.mchammer.x;
red.tf.y = red.mchammer.y;
```

Comment: `var metrics:TextLineMetrics = myRoot.container.txtLine1.getLineMetrics(0);
trace("metrics: " + metrics.height);` This code still produces the wrong height. It is definitely more than 7 pixels tall.

Comment: I can confirm that the code from comment above reveals the size in pixels of the textfield at design time. If I change the font size in IDE, it is proven here. 

Also, according to Adobe, TextField.textHeight should return the height of the text in pixels. In my instances, it does not. [Adobe Reference - TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#textHeight)

Comment: It was a known issue in AS2 (IIRC) that the font metrics were just plain wrong. You should research to make sure it gives correct readings in AS3

Comment: are you including the 2 pixel top gutter and the 2 pixel bottom gutter?

Comment: plus the leading gap if it is multiline

Comment: As mentioned in previous comment, the values I'm getting are consistent with the *initial, stage textfield size*. I need the values after the width/height has been set programatically.

Comment: I updated my post and corrected your issue. I have run your test app with my corrections and it works like a champ.

Answer (score 2):

I might have misunderstood your question, but if not, did you try this one?

```
red.tf.y = red.blue.height / 2 - red.tf.height / 2 + red.blue.y;
```

This is centering the textfield (tf) to the blue box vertically.

Basically you get the center y coordinate of the blue rectangle, subtract the center y coordinate of the textfield and then finally add the blue rectangle's y position.

For the best result you need the textfield with autoSize defined, also that the movieclips have (0, 0) reference points.

It's the same horizontally, but with x coordinate and width parameter.

```
red.tf.x = red.blue.width / 2 - red.tf.width / 2 + red.blue.x;
```

Comment: In the second half of my question I mentioned that the main issue is that the height is not being reported correctly. This answer unfortunately serves no relevance.

Comment: I see. Then I don't understand what size you mentioned. If you set autoSize of the textfield, the actual object will surround the text you typed in and the height of the textfield will be correct. If you want to go deeper than this, then textmetrics is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please don't tell me that it reports the correct height. The whole point of this question is because it *does not* return the correct height. Without trying to be rude, if you'd read the question properly - you would have understood this.